# Applying gradients to table backgrounds in html/css

Tags: html, css, html-table, gradient

I'm attempting to stylise my responsive table and would like for the background to consist of a gradient. My issue is that all styles being applied repeats itself in every cell and so it looks like a horrible image being duplicated.

Gradient I'm using:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(170, 7, 107), rgb(97, 4, 95));
```

Table:

[image: Table with gradient]

I understand that there are many td/th elements in the table and its possible for it to take on its own style, but how would I keep the colour consistent in each row?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/AssistSyed/pen/RwVmELM)

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: We get what you have got. We can see that in the image as well as in Codepen. Can you share a mock showing what you desire? I mean, what final output you want to render?
You could have given background

Comment: Are you wanting the linear gradient (pinkish) background to be on every other row or is it to be on the whole table or....

Comment: Are you using Safari? That seems to split the background so it restarts on every cell(at least on IOS 14)  , but in Chrome (Windows 10) the gradient is continuous along the whole row which is I think what you want.

Comment: @Deepak Yadav thanks for the reply. I want the gradient to be consistent amongst the whole row, rather than just the cell. I'd be glad to put up a desired output within the next hour.

Comment: @A Haworth preferably every other row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add

`background-attachment: fixed;`

where you define the gradient.
If you scroll horizontally it might look a bit off, but this way it will use the browser's left and right edge for generating the gradient.

Comment: This seems like the winning answer. Thank you very much!